# How do I make an input box and a button line up in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.0, and using HTML like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <form data-bind="submit: AddDepartment">
            <input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Department Name" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button doesn't line up with the textbox.  You can see a jsFiddle of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bmccord/e383s/).

What is the proper Bootstrap way of getting them to line up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place `form-inline` class in the form element like so:

```
<form data-bind="submit: AddDepartment" class="form-inline">
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/SufMb/

Comment: As a follow-up, what would I do in the case of a non-form?  For instance I am also using Knockout and have:
        <div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Departments, visible: Departments().length > 0">
            <div class="span5">
                <input type="text" class="input-large" data-bind="value: DepartmentName" />
                <a href="" class="btn btn-small" data-bind="click: $parent.RemoveDepartment"><i class="icon-remove">
                </i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
How do I line those up, but still maintain the spacing between the lines?

Comment: when/why would you use form elements outside of a form? anyway, you would just place `form-inline` on the wrapping div `<div class="row form-inline">`

Comment: If I do that, the spacing between rows disappears.  Here is another fiddle that emulates what knockout does when it creates the rows: http://jsfiddle.net/bmccord/w7pEM/

Comment: any wrapping `div` should have `form-inline`, try it out dude, start putting `form-inline` everywhere. http://jsfiddle.net/fvzWK/

Comment: Yes, but once again, that removes the spacing between the rows.  For instance, if you don't have the small button at all, the text boxes have a space between them that disappears when you add the form-inline which puts all the textboxes touching each other.  Is there  way to preserve the spacing?

Comment: Perfect! You win the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <form data-bind="submit: AddDepartment">
            <div class="input-append">
                <input type="text" class="input-large" placeholder="Department Name" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although that's close, I would rather have the button separate.  It also doesn't look good with small buttons.  See the comments on Phil's answer to see a further fiddle that shows fully what I'm trying to do.